# Where does symfony include the kernel class?

Tags: symfony1

Where does symfony include the kernel class that is used in the AppKernel class ?

Answer (score 1):

in the controller : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app.php#L15

Comment: It's a front controller, actually. Controllers are the classes with xxxAction functions in them.

Comment: The Appkernel class extends the Kernel class.To be able to extend the kernel class, the latter has to be included somewhere.I failed to identify where it was including this kernel class so wanted some help..